# Please burninate dba tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There's a whole Stack Exchange site devoted to [Database Administration](http://dba.stackexchange.com)(and More), having a [dba](/questions/tagged/dba) tag on Stack Overflow isn't of much use and it doesn't describe the question at all - it's more of a meta tag.

So, please burninate [dba](/questions/tagged/dba)

Comment: +1, though I disagree that it's a *meta* tag.  However, it certainly could not stand alone on a SO question, and the questions have very little to do with each other.

Comment: " *Burninate?* "

Comment: @muntoo: [trogdor burninates tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102439/trogdor-are-you-hungry-a-selection-of-tags-to-delete) for breakfast, brunch, lunch, mid-day-snack, tea, dinner, supper, dessert, and mid-night snack.

Comment: @muntoo reference to character on homestarrunner.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of legitimate programming questions related to database administration.  Just because there are non-programming dba questions doesn't mean the dba tag isn't useful for tagging legitimate programming questions that have to do with dba.

Comment: .. and "dba" tag doesn't convey *much* about the question.

Comment: it's still a meta-tag see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @JeffAtwood I suppose this isn't exactly an argument for the merit of the tag, but I've seen a perfectly legitimate question for SO that gets moved because someone saw "dba" in it and thought "Oh I saw a site that specifically deals with dba stuff... that must mean this question isn't valid here".